# Wind turbines in series with opposite rotations

Tags: fluid-dynamics

A wind turbine transforms translational motion of the wind into rotational motion of the blades. Due to angular momentum conservation, there has to be a vortex in the wind field behind the turbine. Therefore, a second turbine with opposite rotation could be placed behind the first one (or even mount both on the same tower), in order to draw the remaining energy out of this vortex and leave the air behind it only translating. However, I haven't consciously seen such a configuration.

See also [contra-rotating propellers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra-rotating) for the same principle in propulsion.

Is the reason why, that it is cheaper (per gained power) to place the next turbine some distance away from first one, instead of drawing the most out of one flux tube by such a double configuration? Would the double configuration probably be more reasonable in cases where real estate is limited (like in Germany, where there are always discussions about places where people don't object to wind turbines in their neighborhood)? Does a double configuration (with its probably more laminar-like flow) allow to place wind turbines more densely because the outflow of one does only minimally disturb the nearby turbines?

Comment: Angular momentum is not conserved in systems attached to the ground. Also, the most efficient designs utilize smooth undisturbed air, and each tower needs to be at least 7 diameters away from the next one for this reason.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou: so the air exiting the propeller is not rotating, is that what you want to say? that sounds pretty weird, considering that each blade is tilted and the air hitting a blade is going to be deflected perpendicular to the rotation axis. I am afraid I don't quite get what you want to say, at least not with respect to my question. Seems almost like you just want to get this question out of your way.

Comment: It is rotating due to friction, but it is also much more unstable (turbulent) which makes extracting energy out of it downstream very inefficient.